# Sensor for bot in pygame map

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'll create a 2D map with objects in pygame and I'm thinking in create a bot to move around the map. (the map view is from above like pokemon fire red much simpler)
How can I put some 'sensors' in the bot. Like, he's moving around, and 3 blocks in his front have an obstacle, how can I detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 2D grid that's filled with the on-screen objects, it's pretty easy to work out the content of cells relative to some position.  Lets assume this particular bot has very "conic" vision:

[image: vision-grid]

If your bot it at `(x,y)`, you need only examine the cells `(x,y-1)`, `(x-1,y-2) (x,y-2) (x+1,y-2)` and `(x-1,y-3) (x,y-3) (x+1,y-3)`.  Obviously with slightly different configurations depending on which way the bot is facing.

This could be generalised into a function:

```
def lookUp( x, y, grid ):
    " Return a list of objects spotted within the field of view "
    result  = []
    offsets = [ (0,-1), (-1,-2), (0,-2), (1,-2), (-1,-3), (0,-3), (1,-3) ]
    for offset in offsets:
        x_off, y_off = offset
        grid_contains = grid[ y + y_off ][ x + x_off ]
        if ( grid_contains != None ):
            result.append( grid_contains )
    return result
```

Where a grid could be constructed for the dimensions of the map:

```
def getEmptyGrid( width, height ):
    grid = []
    for i in range( height ):
        grid.append( [ None ] * width )
    return grid
```

and populated with objects

```
grid[0][0] = Tree( 'conifer' )
grid[3][2] = OtherBot( 'down', 3, 4, 5 )
etc.
```

Comment: sorry for the question, but how would I define 'grid'. I don't actually have a grid, I just have a srceen defined